# SDK Project structure and building with Gradle?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, sdk

As Android Studio became official IDE for Android development, I want to migrate some projects from Eclipse.

I have shared Java library project across multiple Android sample applications.
In Eclipse i refer the Java library project as project dependency, but when i distribute, Ant script generate library jar and copy it to the Android libs folder. I have the ability to debug my code easily without exposing library source code or whole project on distribute.

The final result after distribute must be zipped sample application with documentation and library jar. Any suggestions how can I achieve it in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time searching I decide to write my own custom gradle plugin, but first:

Project structure looks like this:

```
+--------------------+         +---------------------+
|Workspace (Project) |         |Distributed archive  |
|                    |         |                     |
|                    |         |                     |
|    +------------+  |         |  +---------------+  |
|  +-+    SDK     |  |         |  |  SDK Jar lib  |  |
|  | +------------+  |         |  +---------------+  |
|  |                 |         |                     |
|  | +------------+  +--------->  +---------------+  |
|  +->  Sample 1  |  |         |  |  SDK Javadoc  |  |
|  | +------------+  |         |  +---------------+  |
|  |                 |         |                     |
|  | +------------+  |         |  +---------------+  |
|  +->  Sample 2  |  |         |  | Sample source |  |
|    +------------+  |         |  +---------------+  |
|                    |         |                     |
+--------------------+         |  +----------------+ |
                               |  |   Sample APK   | |
                               |  +----------------+ |
                               |                     |
                               +---------------------+
```

So we have workspace with several projects: one for **SDK (pure Java)** and **several samples (Java or Android)** which depends on it and we want to distribute an archive containing:

- SDK Jar file
- SDK Javadoc
- One of the sample applications (source
  bundled with the SDK jar)
- Sample application APK
- Archive name with date, version project and sample name etc...

In Eclipse it's easy - some dependencies, Ant scripts and copy-here, copy-there but the time has come to migrate to Intellij and Android Studio. Here is my successful try to write custom Gradle script:

```
apply plugin: CustomProcessor


import com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin
import com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin

class CustomProcessor implements Plugin<Project> {

    private Project mRoot;
    private List<WrappedProject> mProjects = new ArrayList<>();
    private File mDistribOutput;

    class WrappedProject {
        private final Project project;
        private final Object android;

        WrappedProject(Project project) {
            this.project = project;

            if (isLibrary()) {
                this.android = project.plugins.getPlugin(LibraryPlugin)
                project.logger.info "${project.name}: SDK (API) project detected."
            } else if(isApplication()) {
                project.logger.info "${project.name}: Demo (Sample) project detected."
                this.android = project.plugins.getPlugin(AppPlugin)
            } else {
                project.logger.warn "${project.name}: No Android plugin detected."
                this.android = null
            }
        }

        public boolean isLibrary() {
            return project.plugins.any { p -> p instanceof LibraryPlugin }
        }

        public boolean isApplication() {
            return project.plugins.any { p -> p instanceof AppPlugin }
        }
    }

    @Override
    void apply(Project target) {

        this.mRoot = target
        this.mDistribOutput = new File(target.buildDir, "custom")

        target.configure(target.allprojects) { module ->
            module.afterEvaluate {
                def wrapped = new WrappedProject(module)
                mProjects.add(wrapped)

                if (wrapped.isLibrary()) {
                    addSdkTasks(wrapped.project)
                }

                if (wrapped.isApplication()) {
                    addSampleTasks(wrapped.project)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void addSdkTasks(Object project) {
        project.android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
            if (variant.name.equalsIgnoreCase("release")) {
                Task t = project.task("generate${project.name.capitalize()}Javadoc", type: Javadoc, overwrite: true) {
                    description "Generates Javadoc for $project.name."
                    source = variant.javaCompile.source
                    ext.androidJar = "${project.android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${project.android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
                    classpath = project.files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + project.files(ext.androidJar)
                    exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
                    exclude '**/R.java'
                    failOnError = false
                }
                t.group = 'custom'

                t = project.task("javadoc${project.name.capitalize()}", type: Jar, overwrite: true) {
                    description "Bundles Javadoc into a JAR file for $project.name."

                    classifier = "javadoc"
                    appendix = project.name
                    baseName = mRoot.name
                    version = project.version

                    from project.tasks["generate${project.name.capitalize()}Javadoc"]

                }
                t.group = 'custom'

                t = project.task("jar${project.name.capitalize()}", type: Jar, overwrite: true) {
                    description "Bundles compiled .class files into a JAR file for $project.name."

                    baseName = mRoot.name
                    appendix = project.name
                    version = project.version

                    dependsOn: [project.tasks.assemble ]
                    from variant.javaCompile.destinationDir
                    exclude '**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/R.html', '**/R.*.html'
                }
                t.group = 'custom'
            }
        }
    }

    void addSampleTasks(Object sample) {
        Task t = sample.task(
                "distribute${sample.name.capitalize()}",
                dependsOn: [sample.tasks.assemble, ":sdk:jarSdk", ":sdk:javadocSdk"],
                overwrite: true,
                type: Zip
         ) {
            baseName = mRoot.name
            appendix = project.name
            version = "v${mRoot.project(':sdk').getVersion()}_${getDate()}"
            classifier = 'src'

            from("${project.buildDir}/outputs/apk/") {
                include '**-debug.apk'
                into "apk"
            }

            from("${mRoot.project(':sdk').buildDir}/docs/javadoc") {
                into "doc"
            }

            from("${mRoot.project(':sdk').buildDir}/libs") {
                into "libs"
            }

            from("${mRoot.project(':sdk').buildDir}/libs") {
                into "sample/app/libs"
            }

            from(sample.zipTree("${sample.rootDir}/sample.zip")) {
                into "/"
            }

            from(sample.projectDir) {
                exclude "build"
                exclude "**.iml"
                exclude "build.gradle"
                into "sample/app"
            }
        }
        t.group = 'custom'
    }

    static def getDate() {
        def date = new Date()
        def formattedDate = date.format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
        return formattedDate
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

To generate sample source as openable project in Android Studio I use `sample.zip` which is empty Android Studio project template.